# Provider in Flutter with error "Could not find the correct provider above this X Widget"

Tags: flutter, provider

I'm trying to make dynamic map paths on `urlTemplate`, however, **`Provider` (a.k.a [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider))** throws this error. (*Please refer to the attached image*).

In other pages, the `provider` is working fine except on this page. I want to know the problem of why using `Provider.of(context)` does not work in my case.

Any ideas about this? I was searching all night for this without any luck.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong/latlong.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:user_location/user_location.dart';
import '../model/events.dart';

class MapBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldState = GlobalKey();
  @override
  _MapBoxState createState() => _MapBoxState();
}

class _MapBoxState extends State<MapBox> {
  MapController mapController = MapController();
  UserLocationOptions userLocationOptions;
  List<Marker> markers = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final events = Provider.of<Events>(context);
    final String maps = "${events.itmaps}";
    final String title = "${events.title}";
    userLocationOptions = UserLocationOptions(
      context: context,
      mapController: mapController,
      markers: markers,
    );
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('title')),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new FlutterMap(
            options: new MapOptions(
              center: new LatLng(46.185, 12.963),
              minZoom: 14.0,
              plugins: [
                // ADD THIS
                UserLocationPlugin(),
              ],
            ),
            layers: [
              new TileLayerOptions(
                urlTemplate: maps,
                additionalOptions: {
                  'accessToken':
                      '<XXX>',
                  'id': 'mapbox.mapbox-streets-v7'
                },
              ),
              MarkerLayerOptions(markers: markers),
              userLocationOptions,
            ],
            mapController: mapController,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Here's my `Events` class:

```
class Events { 
   final String imagePath, title, itmaps;
   Events({this.imagePath, this.title, this.itmaps}); 
}
```

Comment: What ProviderWidget/Model/Class are you using in `Events` class ?

Comment: in my Events class i have "itmaps" that must be dynamic and must hold different map urls, same happens with the title

Comment: Can you share your Event Class?

Comment: I think you should try removing your StatefulWidget and convert it to a Stateless if you aren't overriding any StatefulWidget's methods.

Comment: i've tried and it's the same thing

Comment: class Events {
  final String imagePath,
      title,
      itmaps,

  Events({
    this.title,
    this.itmaps,
  });
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to share where and how you "provided" the instance/value of your `Events` object.

Clearly, the error messages states that it is looking for the ancestors, or at least the parent widgets of MapBox, that provides `Events`.

Assuming that your `Events` should be utilized globally in your app, you can do something like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Events {
  final String imagePath, title, itmaps;
  Events({this.imagePath, this.title, this.itmaps});
}

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // Creating an instance of events
  Events _declaredEvents = Events(
    imagePath: "https://somepath.com",
    title: "sometitle",
    itmaps: "somemaps",
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider(
      create: (_) => _declaredEvents, // IMPORTANT: Create the object to be provided
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: FirstPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Based on the context of this page, look for the type `Events` that was provided by the top level widget/s
    Events _providedEvents = Provider.of<Events>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(_providedEvents.title), // Utilised the provided object here
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.